# Extension 'Search Result' cannot format vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ide, react-boilerplate

I am using prettier and kite as my formatters for my react app in vscode. Everytime i use the shortcut: `shift` + `alt` + `f` i get the error: `Extension 'Search Result' cannot format vscode`. Even when i highlight and do manually it doesn't work. What do i do?

Comment: what is shown when you `ctrl + shift + p` and search for "Format Document with..." & hit enter?

Comment: It displays my formatters lol. I decided to configure the default one so now it works fine thanks!

Comment: just FYI, you can set default formatters per language/file-type in your User or Workspace settings so that you dont have to do this every time. For example: `"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }`

Comment: yes thanks @andrewkeithly